# Histogram Intervals

Tags: probability

I would like to know if there is any reason to choose some unusual numbers as 
the histogram edges? Let me explain this better.

At one point in my statistics book ( Principle of statistics by Bulmer) there is table of the frequency distribution of the weights of some coins. As you can see in the picture below.

[image: Coin frequency distribution]

Right after that the books make a histogram of this distribution. The intervals of the histogram are the following ones: $$ [-\infty, 9.95], [9.95,10.95],[10.95,11.95], [11.95,11.95], [12.95,13.95], [12.95,13.95]$$ and so on. I would like to know why the book opted to pick those numbers rather than some more round ones like $10,11,12$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, picking bin size for histograms is an imperfect procedure.

But in this case, it seems as though they picked these bin interval endpoints to avoid the situation of having an endpoint coincide with a measured value.

If the bins were $[9,10], [10,11], \ldots$, where would you put the pennies that weighed 10g? In the $[9,10]$ bin or the $[10,11]$ bin?

Comment: I see it now. So it is always a good habit to use some non integer bin sizes for histograms, right?

Comment: @PedroDreyer No, not necessarily. What if your measurements are 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, etc? Then a perfectly acceptable interval choice would be $[0,1], [1,2], [2,3],\ldots$.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thank you very much.